# Flex cuts off child items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code structure

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img {
  width: 100%
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg"/>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
       <div><button>Button1</button><div>
       <div><button>Button2</button><div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is the footer to occupy its original width and height(height: 144px) , and make the content scrollable based on the available space according to screen resolution.Currently, the footer is getting cut off on some screens. I've tried  changing the flex values for content and footer, but it doesn't work.Thanks

Comment: I feel like there should be more here in the `HTML`. Tell me more about that `img`. How much space should it occupy?

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: It should be occupying whatever space is left, based on screen resolution.I havent set the height of the img, but the width is set to 100%,.This is to not destroy the image

Comment: please add some content in image and divs. thanks

Comment: @XenioGracias Added

Comment: `img` tag in the HTML provided in your question has an error, it should not be `<img src=""src/>` but it should be `<img src="src"/>`

Comment: @Code_Ninja changed

Comment: Now all you need to do is give some content to `content` div and then set `max-height` of that div, and you will have a scroll in that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit your parent to the height of the screen so the footer is always visible, you need to set a height of 100% on your div (and body and html) and also move the image inside your content container (or have a seperate one that will scroll if it too large for the screen)

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  display:block;
  width: 100%
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div><button> Button1 </button></div>
      <div><button> Button2 </button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! .But the content div contains text, which I want to be scrollable.This doesn't contain the img

Comment: @user3615045 your image is a problem - if you put it inside the parent flex container, then what happens when the image is too big for the screen?  What do you expect to happen as the footer will be pushed off by the image - if you have it in your content div, you can add text and the image and both will scroll and keep the footer on screen

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers please do not deface other people's posts with edits to their code that clearly change the way things work

Answer (score 0):

I think setting your parent height to 100vh and giving your footer a fixed height should fix it:

https://codepen.io/chrishalley/pen/zbwRMw

```
    body {
  margin: 0;  
}

.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color: orangered;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}

.footer {
  height: 144px;
}
```